# How to get the dropdown menu open / close when i click on its parent or outside

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down menu that opens and closes when i click on its parent li element. But when i put the code for closing it when ever the user clicked outside the menu, this makes clicking on the parent li no longer closes the menu, but only opens it.

this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Courses</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this is CSS:

```
 *{padding: 0;margin: 0}
li{list-style-type: none}
.menu{background: #333;display: block}
.menu:after, .menu:before{content: '';display: table;clear: both}
.menu>li{display: inline-block;float: left}
.menu a{display: block;text-decoration: none;color: #f9f9f9;padding: 6px 10px;background: #333}
.menu a:hover{ background: #000; }
.dropdown-menu{position: absolute;max-height: 0;overflow: hidden;transition: max-height 1s ease}
.open .dropdown-menu{max-height: 30rem}
```

and Jquery:

```
(function($){
  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
  });

  // This code to hide the dropdown menu 
  // when the user click outside the menu

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){

    $(".dropdown-menu").each(function( index ) {
      if(e.target !== $(this)) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
      }
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/q5eg9cwq/

Comment: Can you check it and explain what the problem is?

Comment: the problem is: when you click a.dropdown-toggle it opens the menu, but when you click on it again to close the menu it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a check on document click with each element with `class='dropdown-menu'`. So   `if(e.target !== $(this))` would always be true.
You need to intercept the condition only once ( I did it by comparing the class attribute on the clicked element ) and remove the class through each loop. Also in order to avoid event propagation to `$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click'` , you would have to use `e.preventDefault()`.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
    var eleNotFound = false;
    if($(e.target).attr("class") !== "dropdown-toggle") 
    {
          eleNotFound = true;
         $(".dropdown-menu").each(function(){
           $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
         });       
    }
     if(eleNotFound)
       e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/5nqh05b2/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have also done few changes in the HTML. instead of setting height, you can trigger visibility. Below is the working code.

```
 (function($) {
  $('a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    var respectivemenu = $(this).next();
    $("ul.dropdown-menu").not(respectivemenu).removeClass('open');
    respectivemenu.toggleClass('open');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });


  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).next().not(".open")) {
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass('open');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/q5eg9cwq/3/

Comment: Your code will lead to more than one dropdown-menu being shown at the same time if more than one of them are exist

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem using another approach, by the help of your answers.

the jQuery code should be:

```
(function($){
  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open').siblings().removeClass('open');
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('dropdown-toggle')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').parent().removeClass('open');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```